# OnClickListener in ViewHolder not being entered

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, android-viewholder

I have a recycler view displaying all posts made by a user in my app. I want the users to be able to click on one of the posts and be brought to a new fragment where they can only see the post they have chosen.

When I run my code, and click on one of the posts, the OnCLickListener isn't even triggered.

I have tried adding break points on public void OnClick but it never gets triggered. I have tried adding the OnClick to the onBindViewHolder but I understand this isn't a good idea.

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder> {
public List<Post> postList;
private Context context;
private static OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

public PostAdapter(){
}

public interface OnItemClickListener{
    void onItemClick(View v, int position);
}

public void updateList(List<Post> list){
    postList = list;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView postName, postUsername, postDate, postTime, postContent, postId;

    PostViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        this.postName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        this.postUsername = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        this.postDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        this.postTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        this.postContent = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.content);
        this.postId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.postId);
        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = PostViewHolder.super.getAdapterPosition();
                onItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, position);
                System.out.println("doesn't even make it here");

            }
        });
    }
}

public PostAdapter(List<Post> postList, Context context){
    this.postList = postList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public PostAdapter.PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.all_posts_layout, parent, false);
    return new PostAdapter.PostViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PostViewHolder holder, int position){
    Post post = postList.get(position);
    holder.postUsername.setText(String.valueOf(post.getUsername()));
    holder.postName.setText(String.valueOf(post.getName()));
    holder.postDate.setText(String.valueOf(post.getDate()));
    holder.postTime.setText(String.valueOf(post.getTime()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount(){
    return this.postList.size();
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

```
<---card layout for each individual post---->

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="130dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:elevation="60dp">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/search_term_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="1dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Name"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/username"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/name"
                    android:text="Username"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
                    android:text="Date"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/username"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/username"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:text="Time"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/content"
                    android:layout_width="315dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/name"
                    android:text="Content"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/postId"
                    android:text="ID"
                    android:layout_below="@id/content"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

<---recycler view to display all posts------>

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/filterBtn"
                android:text="Filter"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/update_post_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Everything looks fine, maybe the view in xml is market with a attribute like clickable=false or disabled=true or something like this.
Also in some cases click event cannot been dispatched well to recycler view, maybe a bad configuration of recyclerview parent. For example when recycler view is placed in bad configured CoordinatorLayout there can appear problems with click event dispatch.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I've updated my questions with my xml relevant to this particular fragment. I don't have any attributes like clickable=false or disabled=true. I also tried to change around my layouts to see if their placement had anything to do with messing up the onclick but I've had no luck!

Comment: Added an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like your `ScrollView` consumes click event. Try to remove it or replace with `NestedScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it in onCreateViewHolder on that view. Also init it in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Update code according to this

```
public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder, View.OnClickListener {
    TextView postName, postUsername, postDate, postTime, postContent, postId;

    PostViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        //init view
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have done this but now I am only seeing this in the logcat when I click on one of the items: D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1

Answer (score 0):

```
**=> You just need to change onBindViewHolder() method code
=> Add click listener on this method.
=> Your code should be like this.**

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PostViewHolder holder, int position){
    Post post = postList.get(position);
    holder.postUsername.setText(String.valueOf(post.getUsername()));
    holder.postName.setText(String.valueOf(post.getName()));
    holder.postDate.setText(String.valueOf(post.getDate()));
    holder.postTime.setText(String.valueOf(post.getTime()));

 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = PostViewHolder.super.getAdapterPosition();
                onItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, position);
                System.out.println("doesn't even make it here");

            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but am getting these errors in the logcat: V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1

Comment: You can not add ScrollView inside your card layout. Remove scroll view from card layout it's will work.

Comment: You can't add scrollview with RecyclerView.
Because both are vertical scroll.